# How to download a multiple PDF Files in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, pdf, asyncstorage

I'm currently building a React Native application that should be able to work in offline mode. The data will be fetched from the API whenever user has internet connection and call "refresh" action.

So I would like to know the best approach to download the pdf`s files to the mobile storage, where user will be able to view them in aplication preview.

My apprehension is mostly about the pdf files, because application will download more than 100+ pdf files on update, once a month.

I'm currently having data in async storage, with the name of the pdf files, and also ready server with all the pdf files that I need to download on user`s mobile.

Answer (score 1):

To download pdf you can use [react-native-blob-util](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-blob-util),
there is also an alternative option [rn-fetch-blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob).

For upload files you can use
[react-native-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs)

You can get an example from the package repository.